# how to create a computeBMI arrow function that expects a user parameter, but immediately destructures it in weight,height,country

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i want to create a computeBMI arrow function and pass it a parameter of a user object, i tried the destructuring method but i still have the same error " Your BMI calculation is not correct. Review the instructions and continue." here is what i did.

```
const computeBMI = ({weight,height,country}) =>{
        const countries = ['Chad', 'Sierra Leone', 'Mali', 'Gambia', 'Uganda', 'Ghana', 'Senegal', 'Somalia', 'Ivory Coast', 'Israel'];
        const nuser = {

          weight: weight,

          height:height,

          country: country

        }; let meter= height*0.3048;
         for(let c in countries){

           if(countries[c] === country) return (weight/(meter**2))*0.82;
         }
        return (weight/(meter**2));
      }
```

Comment: I don't see the use of destructuring in your code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Comment: He is using desructuring in the paramaters ({weight,height,country})

Comment: is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the function? When using destructuring you need to pass in an object.

```
computeBMI({ weight: 120, height: 1.6, country: 'Sierra Leone' });
```

```js
const computeBMI = ({weight,height,country}) =>{
  const countries = ['Chad', 'Sierra Leone', 'Mali', 'Gambia', 'Uganda', 'Ghana', 'Senegal', 'Somalia', 'Ivory Coast', 'Israel'];
  const nuser = {

    weight: weight,

    height:height,

    country: country

  };
  
  let meter= height*0.3048;
  
  for(let c in countries){

    if(countries[c] === country) return (weight/(meter**2))*0.82;
  }
  return (weight/(meter**2));
}

const bmi = computeBMI({ weight: 120, height: 1.6, country: 'Sierra Leone' });

console.log(bmi);
```

Comment: ```const letsCalculateBMI = ()  =>{
        let query = document.querySelector('select');
        let user = getSelectedUser(query.value);
        let bmi=computeBMI(user);
        console.log(bmi);
        document.querySelector('#bi').innerHTML=bmi;
    
      } ;``` this is how am calling the function